# How to set different transition animations on Navigator.pop() in Flutter, according to user action?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter project, that has multiple screens, I want to create one screen with 2 buttons:

- the first button closes the current screen with `Navigator.pop()` with a transition where the current screen disappears to the right
- the second button also closes the current screen with `Navigator.pop()`, but this time the screen disappears to the bottom

Every example I've found so far allows me to set only one possible transition when I pop my screen.

Also, I use named routes to navigate in my app.

How can I customize the pop animation according to the button clicked by the user?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `pageRouteBuilder` for custom navigation animations. Check out this [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vPF2IqCJ9Q).

Comment: I've checked all of that already, and unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question: how to choose 2 differents transition animations on `Navigator.pop()` according to the pressed button?

Comment: you should make use of a custom `Navigator` with a custom `TransitionDelegate` which can take parameters while poping and decide which transition to use

Answer (score 3):

whatever you define as a route animation it would be reverse and use as pop navigation .
in your case you can use different animations for pushing each one .
you can create your custom one and define the animation and use it instead of `material page router`

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyCustomRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget widget;
  MyCustomRoute({this.widget})
    : super(
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
          return widget;
        },
        transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
          return new ScaleTransition(
            scale: new Tween<double>(
              begin: 0.0,
              end: 1.0,
            ).animate(
                CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: animation,
                  curve: Interval(
                    0.00,
                    0.50,
                    curve: Curves.bounceIn,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            child: ScaleTransition(
                     scale: Tween<double>(
                       begin: 1.5,
                       end: 1.0,
                     ).animate(
                       CurvedAnimation(
                         parent: animation,
                         curve: Interval(
                           0.50,
                           1.00,
                           curve: Curves.easeIn,
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     child: child,
                   ),
           );
         }
      );
}
```

to implement

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(context,
      new MyCustomRoute (widget: Secondpage()));
},
```

to pop

```
 onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop();// will reverse the animation
                },
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer my question: what if I have 2 buttons on my screen, and each one set a custom (and different!) transition animation when I pop the screen?

Comment: oh, you can use `push`  instead of `pop` and use different  ` transition animation` for each one , in each push you can back to previous page ,

Comment: also if you don't want to go back to where the buttons exist you can use `PushAndRemoveUntil`  instead of `push` like this 
 `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,MyCustomRoute ( widget:SeconPage()),(Route<dynamic> route) => false, );`

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that, I'll try that very soon. Thanks!
But one more question: if I use `push()` instead of `pop()`, to go back to the previous page, will I have then another instance of that page?

Comment: yes , but you can use `pushReplacement` , it Replaces the current route of the navigator by pushing the given route and then disposing the previous route once the new route has finished animating in. kind of like `pushandremoveuntil`,try that and tell me the result ,i'm Glad to help